# Solve the partial differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve $(y^2 + z^2 - x^2)p - 2xyq + 2xz = 0$ where $p = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $q = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

I wrote the auxiliary equations:

$$
\frac{dx}{y^2+z^2-x^2} = \frac{dy}{-2xy} = \frac{dz}{-2xz}
$$

Using the second and third terms, I got $\frac{y}{z} = c$, where $c$ is a constant.

I am stuck now as I don't know how to use the first term to get another solution independent of the first on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Each of the ratios equal to:

$$
\frac{2xdx + 2ydy + 2zdz}{-2x(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}
$$

So the other solution is

$$
\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{y} = k
$$